# S3: Service that replace access to the local file system with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud

I have an application that heavily uses the local file system. We need to port the application to use S3. What services are out there that will automate the access to the S3 without having to changing the source code of the application.
These services somehow mask the S3 FS as a local FS.

Thanks.

Comment: Check for Expandrive or similar - they let you mount S3 as a virtual local drive.

Comment: How is their performance?

Comment: Depends on your needs. But in general anything that maps external stuff as a filesystem is significantly slower than the local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

See [FuseOverAmazon (or s3fs)](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) but keep in mind that S3 is an eventual consistency data store and your app should be architected to take that into account. It's also important to note that trying to mount an S3 bucket as a file system has very poor performance.

Comment: Performance was horrible. Why is the performance would be so bad compared to using the amazon S3 API? I expected a little degradation on performance but not huge.

Comment: S3 was not designed to be used as a file system, it's merely an object store with great redundancy and eventual consistency. Any solution that tries to emulate a file system on top of it will not be able to utilize the features that S3 offers in the way that they were designed to be used. It's best to design your app to work with S3 if it's a good candidate for your use case as opposed to trying to duck-tape a solution together with a file system emulator over S3.

Comment: So what's the alternative? I want to run my application on a PaaS. But the files have to be stored on the cloud. Is there other cloud based FS that's similar to S3 but designed differently?

Comment: If you run your application on an EC2 server, check out [Amazon EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/). That service is the equivalent of a physical hard-drive, but part of the AWS cloud. It's not similar to S3 though, because they serve completely different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs). Our project is an alternative to “s3fs” project, main advantages comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently the project is in the “beta” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

Hope it helps !